# Android Studio Text View not Changing

Tags: android

I'm making an app to display the current latitude and longitude of the device. Although when I try to change the TextView that is supposed to display the coordinates it doesn't change the text value. Even when I try to change the value to a random string the text on screen still doesn't change.

```
package com.example.localbrewbeta;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btnGetStarted = findViewById(R.id.btnGetStarted);
        btnGetStarted.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            setContentView(R.layout.latlong_test);

            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }

            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            AtomicReference<Double> longitude = null;
            AtomicReference<Double> latitude = null;

            final Button btnLocTest = findViewById(R.id.btnLocTest);
            btnLocTest.setOnClickListener(v2 -> {
                final TextView tvGeoLocate = findViewById(R.id.tvGeoLocateTest);

                longitude.set(location.getLongitude());
                latitude.set(location.getLatitude());

                if (latitude.get() == null || longitude.get() == null) {
                    tvGeoLocate.setText("Location is Null");
                } else {
                    tvGeoLocate.setText(latitude + " " + longitude);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#6f4e37"
    android:backgroundTint="#E46F4E37"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetStarted"
        android:layout_width="303dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/get_started"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:backgroundTint="#66432a"
        android:background="@drawable/default_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.852"
        app:rippleColor="#7E2626" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnGetStarted"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_placeholder_image" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

latlong_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGeoLocateTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/placeholder"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLocTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvGeoLocateTest" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use setContentView like that in your `Button.onClick`... I believe if you created another activity for the `TextView`, and moved to it on the first button click, then within the second activity, you could change the `TextView` contents.

Comment: I don't think you can use `setContentView(R.layout.latlong_test)` in the `OnClickListener.onClick`. And his is the first time I've seen this method used in this way, maybe @NitzanDaloomy 's comment is the answer you want.